# Devexpress can I update project with devexpress 12 to 17 but it's still run well on Windows XP?

Tags: devexpress, windows-xp, devexpress-windows-ui

My company has used the Devexpress 12 since 10 years ago and now I'm researching how to update it's version to newest version like 17.2.6 but I'm confusing that the project will not run on Windows XP anymore, that's all, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current major is v17.2
it still supports the .net 4 and works well on the win xp with last updated .net 4.
so DevExpress controls works well on .net 4, but may be a lacks on desktop features (WPF platform for example). WinForms should works well.
[documentation](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Versions.xml) says 17.2.6, Supported Frameworks: .NET Framework 4.0+
but please note that Win XP is [currently not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20Windows%20XP%20Service%20Pack%203) by the Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry, what is "MS" in your answer?